# Layout problem in Android

Tags: android, layout

Following is my XML code. Please ignore the colors. I put them there for testing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:background="#ff0000">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:background="#ffffff">
        <TabHost android:id="@+id/distributionTabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#00ff00" />
                <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ff0000">
                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ITCCGListContainer" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <ListView android:id="@+id/ITCCGList" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"  android:background="#00ff00"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When I use this for an activity, the listview's height is very small and not occupying the remaining blank space. What I want is the Listview to occupy as much space as required for its contents and have the whole Activity scroll. For that i have enclosed the whole thing in a scrollview.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `android:fillViewport="true"` property for your `ScrollView`, so it to fit the screen partition dedicated for your `Activity`.